# What is this line with multiple values on both sides of an assignment doing?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how the 5th line is structured.

```
def removeElement(nums, val):
    start, end = 0, len(nums) - 1
    while start <= end:
        if nums[start] == val:
            nums[start], nums[end], end = nums[end], nums[start], end - 1
        else:
            start +=1
    return nums
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with a list comprehension.

Comment: There is no list comprehension in that code...

Comment: It is not list comprehension. Its just an assignment of 3 variables in python.

Comment: That is not a list comprehension. The 5th line is a multiple assignment. `nums[end]` is saved in `nums[start`, `nums[start]` is saved in `nums[end]`, etc

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple assignment of three variables

In python, you can write these three lines in one line.
So here's a simple value exchange between two variable, usually you would write something like below

```
value1 = 1 // let
value2 = 2 // let

temp = value1
value1 = value2
value2 = temp
```

now you can

```
value1,value2 = value2,value1
```

That's it

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a list comprehension, that is just python's tuple packing and unpacking at work. Essentially, it simultaneously runs these three lines:

```
nums[start] = nums[end]
nums[end] = nums[start]
end = end - 1
```

If these were run in sequence, the first two lines would conflict with each other and cause `nums[start]` and `nums[end]` to take on the original value of `nums[end]`. This code allows the two values to be swapped.

Comment: Makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

So you traverse the list and once you get to the value, which is now at index start. Then you swap the last value with this new value and that's basically what the function does.
But again, this is not list comprehension and if you want to remove an element just use del l[index] or use remove